# generate friendly url link in a smarty template file with prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

using latest prestashop from git.

I'm trying to create a link to a page I created under the `design`->`Pages` tab of the admin panel.

I can browse link by going to http://prestashop.ufk:8080/he/content/6-test-1

the id of the page is `6` and the friendly url I chose is `test-1`.

how do I convert this to a `{url}` smarty link ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{$link->getCMSLink('6')}`. If you get undefined variable error (can happen in your module templates) then you need to define `$link` before loading your template.

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('link', $this->context->link);
```